# Unable to create ARM virtual device on "Qt creator for Android".

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, qt5

Am trying to configure `Qt for Android development` on my windows 7 machine. I have downloaded the `latest Android Studio, NDK, Apache Ant 1.9.7 and Qt Creator from qt.io (Qt 5.6.0 for Android (Windows 32-bit, 1.1 GB))`. 
I am able to create AVD in Android Studio and was able to start AVD and deploy an application I created on Android studio successfully.

Now, I wanted to configure Qt for Android, so that I can continue my development on Qt. I am able to build the Qt application for x86 desktop version. But, I have problem in creating ARM virtual device on Qt Creator to to deploy the application on to the target. I notice only x86 CPU/ABI while creating a new AVD as shown below:

[image: Create a new AVD, and unable to see ARM under CPU/ABI dropdown]

Comment: For me it works without an env var for ant. If you only build without running, does it build an apk?

Comment: I have not tried that, I will check that real quick. Do I need to install Ministro ?

Comment: Not unless you plan on using it. I don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your virtual devices are all x86 based, while your Qt kit builds for ARM. This will not matter for Android Studio, since it is not native code but Java, but Qt is C++ code and you cannot target a x86 device with an ARM compiler.

Either install Qt for Android x86 or create an ARM virtual device.

Comment: I have installed `Qt 5.6.0 for Android (Windows 32-bit, 1.1 GB)` from http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/

I understand what you are saying, but I had a problem with creating an ARM virtual device too. I have attached few more screen shots about what problem I am facing while adding the virtual device.

Comment: That version should contain 3 different Qt builds, for windows x86, for android x86 and for android arm. As for not being able to create an ARM device, run the Android SDK manager and install some of the ARM packages for your specific android target API.

Comment: Also, your kits showing red flags - that's not OK. Hover over the red icon to show a popup on what's wrong and post that too, but from the looks of it, you have the wrong compiler set up.

Comment: @user12345 - change the compiler to Android GCC arm 4.9, change the Qt version to Qt for Android armv7

Comment: You are still trying to run amr code on x86 target - as I said already, create an arm abi virtual device.

Comment: Yeah agree. But for some reason am unable to create an arm abi virtual device from Qt creator. The picture number 6 (under EDIT 1) is what am seeing when I try to create a virtual device and by default I see only one option x86. I see some video tutorials and I see that there are multiple cpu options shown in the same window for those guys. Am not sure what am missing. Is it the SDK, I have not specifically installed SDK - I installed android studio and gave the path of SDK (from android studio) same in Qt Creator.

Comment: The Qt doc says you need the SDK, not android studio. Maybe that's the problem. I have only installed arm targets from the SDK, so I only have arm for the virtual devices.

Comment: There is no such thing as " the arm SDK for Qt Creator`. What you need is the regular android sdk.

Comment: ok. How's it different from what already have on my machine.  I have installed it as per the information in Qt doc from the website below
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

I have installed the below one for SDK. 
`Windows  android-studio-bundle-143.2790544-windows.exe
Includes Android SDK (recommended)  1181 MB
(1238568304 bytes)  c6abe7980dbb7d1d9887`

There is also just tools package in the same website:
`Windows  installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe
 144 MB
(151659917 bytes)  f9b59d7241364`

are you saying I should install this and try ?

Comment: I don't know how is it different because I don't have it and can't compare. What I know is that if you have the SDK and you have installed an arm package, you can create a virtual device for it.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was working on Android studio installed on my Windows 7 machine. And, when I wanted to work on "Qt for Android" I have set the Android SDK and NDK paths in Qt Creator to the same locations that I used in Android Studio,  and for some reason I was unable to create an ARM virtual device in Qt Creator.

Based on the previous answer provided by @ddriver I ran SDK Manager and installed ARM packages. Now am able to deploy my application.